# can't pass std::vector<std::unique_ptr<>> to std::thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11, unique-ptr

I created a **threadpool** which captures a function and arguments into tuples and then perfect forwards when the task is dequeued.

However I am unable to pass a vector of unique_ptr's to the thread by rvalue. A simplified project is below:

```
#include <future>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template <typename F, typename... Args>
typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type pushTask(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    using result_type = typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type;

    // create a functional object of the passed function with the signature std::function<result_type(void)> by creating a
    // bound Functor lambda which will bind the arguments to the function call through perfect forwarding and lambda capture
    auto boundFunctor = [func = std::move(std::forward<F>(f)),
                         argsTuple = std::move(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...))](void) mutable->result_type
    {
        // forward function and turn variadic arguments into a tuple
        return result_type();
    };

    // create a packaged task of the function object
    std::packaged_task<result_type(void)> taskFunctor{ std::move(boundFunctor) };
}

 int main(int argc, char *argv [])
 {
     auto testvup = [](std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>&& vup)
    {

    };
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vup;
    pushTask(testvup, std::move(vup));
}
```

I get the following compiler error with VS2015 rather I use the std::function or std::packaged_task

Severity    Description Project File    Line

```
Error   error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function Stack   xmemory0    659
```

passing other arguments by rvalue including `std::vector` works.

Has anyone else run across this or have suggestions.

Comment: `std::function` performs type erasure. It is copyable, hence it requires copyability of the function object you store within it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25330716

Comment: yes my choice of std::function was a poor example.  However, I get the same error with std::packaged_task which is supposed take move constructable objects

Answer (score 2):

C++ Standard section §20.9.11.2.1 [func.wrap.func]

> `template<class F> function(F f);`
>
> `template <class F, class A> function(allocator_arg_t, const A& a, F
>   f);`
>
> Requires: F shall be **CopyConstructible**. f shall be Callable for
>   argument types ArgTypes and return type R. The copy constructor and
>   destructor of A shall not throw exceptions.

Your lambda function `boundFunctor` is a move only type (because it captures move only types, since `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied)

Hence, `boundFunctor` is not copyable and not suitable as an argument to an `std::function`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.   However, when I use std::packaged_task<result_type(void)> taskFunctor{ std::move(boundFunctor) };
} instead of std::function I get the same results.  packaged_task is supposed to take move constructable objects.

Comment: @bryanzim : works for me, [see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49459fa749ae85f2) , I dont have VS2015 though

Comment: Thanks for alternate verification.  It must be a Microsoft Specific bug in the implementation of packaged_task.  I should file an error report with them.