# Moving a lambda: once you've move-captured a move-only type, how can the lambda be used?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, move-semantics, stdmove

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20669290/1858225) explains how to move-capture a variable within a lambda in C++14.

But once you've move-captured an un-copyable object (such as a `std::unique_ptr`) within a lambda, you cannot copy the lambda itself.

This would be fine if you could *move* the lambda, but I get a compile error when trying to do so:

```
using namespace std;

class HasCallback
{
  public:
    void setCallback(std::function<void(void)>&& f)
    {
      callback = move(f);
    }

    std::function<void(void)> callback;
};

int main()
{
  auto uniq = make_unique<std::string>("Blah blah blah");
  HasCallback hc;
  hc.setCallback(
      [uniq = move(uniq)](void)
      {
        std::cout << *uniq << std::endl;
      });

  hc.callback();
}
```

This produces the following error with `g++` (I've attempted to copy only the relevant line):

```
error: use of deleted function ‘main()::<lambda()>::<lambda>(const main()::<lambda()>&’
```

...implying, I think, that my attempt to move the lambda has failed.

`clang++` gives a similar error.

I tried explicitly `move`ing the lambda (even though it's a temporary value), but that did not help.

**EDIT:** The answers below adequately address the compile errors produced by the above code. For an alternate approach, simply `release` the unique pointer's target value into a `std::shared_ptr`, which *can* be copied. (I'm not writing this as an answer, because that would assume that this is an XY problem, but the underlying reason why `unique_ptr` can't be used in a lambda that gets converted to a `std::function` is important to understand.)

**EDIT 2:** Hilariously enough, I just realized `auto_ptr` would actually do the right thing here (!), as far as I can tell. It acts essentially like `unique_ptr`, but allows copy-construction in place of move-construction.

Comment: I think setCallback should get parameter by value rather than rvalue reference, am I wrong?

Comment: @Slava That's what I originally had, but it gave the same error. I thought taking the rvalue reference would permit (/force) the lambda to be move-constructed, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can move **the lambda**, that's fine. That's not what your problem is though, you're trying to instantiate a `std::function` with a noncopyable lambda. And the:

```
template< class F > 
function( F f );
```

constructor of [`function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) does:

> 5) Initializes the target with a **copy** of `f`.

This is because [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

> satisfies the requirements of CopyConstructible and CopyAssignable.

Since `function` has to be copyable, everything you put into it must also be copyable. And a move-only lambda does not meet that requirement.

Comment: ....huh. Thank you-- I was having a very difficult time parsing those error messages even for this simple case. Is there any way to change the signature to work, short of using a universal-ref-qualified template parameter instead of `std::function`?

Comment: @KyleStrand It doesn't matter what the parameter is, you just can't construct the `function`. If you need something type-erased, you'd have to write a movable `function` equivalent.

Comment: @Barry there are move only std::functions alternatives already out there just to mention two: https://github.com/Naios/Function2 and https://github.com/potswa/cxx_function

Comment: @Barry I meant using the lambda directly (without converting it to `function` or any other similar type) by writing a template function that would use the lambda itself as the template type.

Comment: @KyleStrand Oh sure, that's fine. Moving the lambda around is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 18):

`std::function` is not a lambda! It's a wrapper that can be constructed from any type of callable, including a lambda. `std::function` requires that the [callable be copy-constructible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25330716/241631), which is why your example fails.

A move-only lambda can be moved again as shown below.

```
template<typename F>
void call(F&& f)
{
    auto f1 = std::forward<F>(f);  // construct a local copy
    f1();
}

int main()
{
  auto uniq = make_unique<std::string>("Blah blah blah");
  auto lambda = [uniq = move(uniq)]() {
        std::cout << *uniq << std::endl;
      };
//  call(lambda);   // doesn't compile because the lambda cannot be copied
  call(std::move(lambda));
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8f276c0060819f1)

Comment: Ack. I knew `std::function` is not a lambda, but since lambda is convertible to `std::function` I wasn't keeping the distinction clear in my mind.

Comment: So how to implement the HasCallback in original code? What I mean is, how to save the move-only lambda into a move only container or move only data struct?

Comment: @alpha You would either need to use the lambda directly without converting it to another type (i.e. the function that calls a lambda would need to take the lambda as a template-type argument), or use a different function-class (there are various alternatives to `std::function` in the wild, or you could design your own).