# Lambda to function using generalized capture impossible?

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function

A lambda can be easily converted to std::function though this seems to be impossible when the lambda uses generalized capture with a unique_ptr. Likely an underlying std::move is missing. Is there a workaround for this or is this a known issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto lambdaGeneralizedCaptureOk = [t = std::make_unique<int>(1)]()
      {
        std::cout << *t << std::endl;
      };
    lambdaGeneralizedCaptureOk();
    
    // error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete]’
    std::function<void()> lambdaToFunctionGeneralizedCaptureNok = [t = std::make_unique<int>(2)]()
      {
        std::cout << *t << std::endl;
      };
    lambdaToFunctionGeneralizedCaptureNok();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should include the error message in the question. The "is it a known issue" part can be asnwered by reading the error message

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59967794/rationale-behind-making-stdfunction-require-copy-constructor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a workaround for this or is this a known issue?

`std::function` requires that the underlying callable must be copyable, since the lambda object in your example is move-only, this is ill-formed.

It's worth noting that C++23 introduced [`move_only_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/move_only_function/move_only_function), which does exactly what you need

```
std::move_only_function<void()> lambdaToFunctionGeneralizedCaptureNok = 
  [t = std::make_unique<int>(2)]() {
    std::cout << *t << std::endl;
   };
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K3cPGxMf7)

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Both MSVC and libstdc++ have implemented `move_only_function`.

Comment: So C++ realized that Rust had it figured out with the `FnOnce` / `Fn` / `FnMut` distinction and made its own version of `FnOnce`. It's so fascinating to see the convergent evolution of these two languages.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is to use a `std::shared_ptr` instead.