# c++ move a lambda to std::function which contains unique_ptr

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a lambda which moved a unique pointer into itself:

```
auto my_ptr = std::make_unique<int>(3);
auto my_lambda = [my_ptr = std::move(my_ptr)]() mutable {
    // ...
};
```

I want to move that lambda into `std::function`:

```
std::function<void()> func = std::move(my_lambda);
```

But I get the error that `std::function target must be copy-constructible`.
Of course if I try to use `auto` instead of `std::function` it works, but it doesn't work for my case. I have a struct which contains `std::function` and you cant use `auto` in a struct.

If there any way of moving the lambda into that function pointer?

Comment: See dupes: [dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486623/moving-a-lambda-once-youve-move-captured-a-move-only-type-how-can-the-lambda) and [dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421346/how-to-create-an-stdfunction-from-a-move-capturing-lambda-expression)

Comment: You could create a `shared_ptr` from `unique_ptr` and capture that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, this is unfortunately `std::function`'s absolute requirement: it requires a copy-constructible callable object. The precludes using any callable object that captures a move-only object.

This is why C++23 introduced [`std::move_only_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/move_only_function/move_only_function).