# Capture std::promise in a lambda C++14

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, promise, c++14

I want to make a state machine which works processes the submitted signals in its own thread. I use Visual Studio 2015, so C++11 and partially C++14 is supported.
Signals are stored in containers. Each signal is represented as an std::function.
I would like to wait from the client until the state machine processes the signal that was submitted, so it is a kind of synchronous signal.

My problem is: I cannot capture an std::promise into a lambda and add it to the container.

```
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <list>

std::list<std::function<int()>> callbacks;

void addToCallbacks(std::function<int()>&& callback)
{
    callbacks.push_back(std::move(callback));
}

int main()
{
    std::promise<int> prom;
    auto fut = prom.get_future();

    // I have made the lambda mutable, so that the promise is not const, so that I can call the set_value
    auto callback = [proms{ std::move(prom) }]() mutable { proms.set_value(5); return 5; };

    // This does not compile
    addToCallbacks(std::move(callback));

    // This does not compile either, however this lambda is a temporal value (lvalue)
    addToCallbacks([proms{ std::move(prom) }]() mutable { proms.set_value(5); return 5; });

    return 0;
}
```

What are the solutions if

- I want to avoid capturing the promise by reference
- I want to avoid capturing a * pointer or a shared_ptr to the promise

It would be nice to embed the promise into the class somehow that the lambda generates. This means that the lambda is not copyable any more, only moveable. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Design review: don't use `std::list` unless you really, really require iterator stability.  Your goal is to have the "return value" both show up in the future (which is somewhere decoupled), and in the return value of the function you call?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`std::function` can only be constructed from functors that are *copyable*. From [func.wrap.func.con]:

> ```
> template<class F> function(F f);
> template <class F, class A> function(allocator_arg_t, const A& a, F f);
> ```
>
> *Requires*: `F` shall be **CopyConstructible**.

`std::promise` is non-copyable, so there's no way to stick a functor with this member into a `std::function`. Period.

Given that you want your functor to actually take ownership of the promise, this doesn't leave you many options. Pretty much `std::shared_ptr<std::promise>`. Any other option either doesn't work (e.g. `std::unique_ptr<std::promise>`), leaves you with a dangling object (e.g. `std::reference_wrapper<std::promise>`), or leaves you with memory-management issues (e.g. `std::promise*`).

---

You could, however, use something other than `std::function`. You can take a look at Yakk's `task` idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25408989/2069064), as well as [dyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp)'s `function_mo` [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/340d6aa74b289b9c), both of which create movable flavors of `std::function`.

Comment: Oh, dyp's `function_mo` is *rude* -- it uses `std::function`, but stores a `hack<F>` which contains a `F` and pretends to be copyable, but said copies simply throw (I think they should `std::terminate` or just do nothing in practice, so they can state that they don't throw).  Basically, it lies to `std::function`, then exposes only the parts of `std::function` that should work.  So long as you can tease a guarantee out of the standard that the copy operations will only be called when you copy the `std::function`, it is safe, but that would require some standard delving...

Comment: Ah; it also requires that the `F` be constructible as `F()`, as `hack(hack const&)` calls `f()` implicitly. -- tangentally, `std::promise<void()>` can be used as a holder of a `std::promise<T()>` that ignores its return value.  Or the OP could just store `std::promise<T()>`s (not sure what the OP is doing with the return values?)

Answer (score 5):

It's trivial to roll your own polymorphic function class. This example fixes the argument and return types, but a little more work could templatise them if desired.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <list>

// declare a non-polymorphic container for any function object that takes zero args and returns an int
// in addition, the contained function need not be copyable
class move_only_function
{
    // define the concept of being callable while mutable
    struct concept
    {
        concept() = default;
        concept(concept&&) = default;
        concept& operator=(concept&&) = default;
        concept(const concept&) = delete;
        concept& operator=(const concept&) = default;
        virtual ~concept() = default;

        virtual int call() = 0;
    };

    // model the concept for any given function object
    template<class F>
    struct model : concept
    {
        model(F&& f)
        : _f(std::move(f))
        {}

        int call() override
        {
            return _f();
        }

        F _f;
    };

public:
    // provide a public interface
    int operator()()  // note: not const
    {
        return _ptr->call();
    }

    // provide a constructor taking any appropriate object
    template<class FI>
    move_only_function(FI&& f)
    : _ptr(std::make_unique<model<FI>>(std::move(f)))
    {}

private:
    std::unique_ptr<concept> _ptr;
};

std::list<move_only_function> callbacks;

void addToCallbacks(move_only_function&& callback)
{
    callbacks.push_back(std::move(callback));
}

int main()
{
    std::promise<int> prom;
    auto fut = prom.get_future();

    // I have made the lambda mutable, so that the promise is not const, so that I can call the set_value
    auto callback = [proms=std::move(prom)]() mutable { proms.set_value(5); return 5; };

    // This now compiles
    addToCallbacks(std::move(callback));

    std::promise<int> prom2;
    auto fut2 = prom2.get_future();

    // this also compiles
    addToCallbacks([proms = std::move(prom2)]() mutable { proms.set_value(6); return 6; });

    for (auto& f : callbacks)
    {
        std::cout << "call returns " << f() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "fut = " << fut.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "fut2 = " << fut2.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
call returns 5
call returns 6
fut = 5
fut2 = 6
```

Comment: You have provided a full solution. This is nice. However I wouldl like to stick more to the core C++ and not introduce such special variants of a functor. I think I will use a smart pointer pointing to the promise and capture it by value. Anyway, thanks for your efforts! I have given you +1 for this post :-)

Answer (score 2):

Good news: C++23 will resolve that long-standing issue.

In the (still evolving future) standard, there is a [`std::move_only_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/move_only_function), which will allow precisely such use cases as detailed here.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple approach may be to use *destructive copy* idiom and wrap movable-only type into trivial **CopyConstructible** struct:

```
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct destructive_copy_constructible
{
    mutable T value;

    destructive_copy_constructible() {}

    destructive_copy_constructible(T&& v): value(std::move(v)) {}

    destructive_copy_constructible(const destructive_copy_constructible<T>& rhs)
        : value(std::move(rhs.value))
    {}

    destructive_copy_constructible(destructive_copy_constructible<T>&& rhs) = default;

    destructive_copy_constructible&
    operator=(const destructive_copy_constructible<T>& rhs) = delete;

    destructive_copy_constructible&
    operator=(destructive_copy_constructible<T>&& rhs) = delete;
};

template <typename T>    
using dcc_t = 
    destructive_copy_constructible<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>;

template <typename T>
inline dcc_t<T> move_to_dcc(T&& r)
{
    return dcc_t<T>(std::move(r));
}

int main()
{
    std::promise<int> result;

    std::function<void()> f = [r = move_to_dcc(result)]()
    {
        r.value.set_value(42);
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Despite the fact that *destructive copy* idiom is considered dangerous and obsoleted by *move* idiom, it still can be useful, at least to cover such `std::function` hole.

Advantage here is zero overhead (no copy/dynamic memory allocations) comparing to proposed `std::shared_ptr` and `move_only_function` solutions. And danger of misusing copied original object is mostly mitigated by using move-like syntax that clearly describes destructive copy/move semantics.

Another useful side effect is that you don't have to declare *entire* lambda mutable to set `std::promise` value because it's already declared so in DCC wrapper.