# C++11 STL container that supports move-only types and has O(1) write-access to beginning and end

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, stl, containers

I am developing an application where I need to **queue up** some **move-only types** and I need **fast** write-**access** **to** the **beginning** and the **end** of the container (mainly adding elements fast).

At first glance I wanted to use `std::deque<T>` but it requires that `T` is copy-constructible, so it won't do the job.

I am now considering `std::vector`, but I'm worried that adding elements to the beginning of the `vector` would be really slow because of reallocating all the stuff.

Any suggestions on such container?

Note on operations I need (on `std::deque`):

- `emplace_back`
- `emplace_front`
- `pop_front`
- `empty`
- `front`

These are the operations used currently (my implementation now uses `std::shared_ptr` to make move-only types copyable)

The exact type I need to queue is the move-only version of `std::function<void()>`. If I try the move-only version with `std::deque` I get the following compiler errors (clang++):

> error: use of deleted function ‘std::packaged_task<_Res(_ArgTypes
>   ...)>::packaged_task(const std::packaged_task<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&)
>   [with _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {}]’ In file included from
>   /home/superuser/Desktop/thread_pool/thread_pool.hpp:32:0,
>                    from /home/superuser/Desktop/thread_pool/test.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/6/future:1513:7: note: declared here
>          packaged_task(const packaged_task&) = delete;

Note that you see `std::packaged_task`, because it is moved into a lambda wrapped by `std::function<void()>`.

Comment: I had the same problem and used `std::list`

Comment: *"it requires that T is copy-constructible"* No it doesn't. (Unless you perform operations on the queue that require elements to be copied. If so, please tell us what operations you need.)

Comment: Moves count as copy.  See [CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable) and [CopyConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible)

Comment: I tried using `std::deque` in my code, but it didn't compile as it wanted to copy.

Comment: @krispetkrispet *"Unless you perform operations on the queue that require elements to be copied. If so, please tell us what operations you need."* Adding elements does not require a copy unless you are doing that wrong. If so, MCVE please. (Would likely make the question a dupe though.)

Comment: Standard advice for these sorts of questions:  Write a class with an API to handle exactly what you need.  Start by implementing it with the simplest thing that could possibly work (in this case, std::vector); optimize when the profiler tells you that you have a problem (and not before).

Comment: @krispetkrispet Could copy constructor requirement be caused by another problem? E.g. you have removed copy constructor and didn't write a move one. What are compiler messages?

Comment: Those operations all work with move-only types if used correctly.

Comment: VTC: need MCVE. As mentioned above, `std::deque` satisfies requirements posted by OP

Comment: @krispetkrispet: Is your move constructor no-throw?  I know vector can only use a non-throwing move constructor (because otherwise it can't achieve its documented exception safety guarantee).  deque is very likely to be the same.

Comment: Of those operations the only one that might need a copy constructor is `front`, are you assigning the result to a reference?

Comment: @imreal I use the result of `front` as follows:  `std::function<void()> fun = std::move(queue.front())` (note that this is right before `pop_front()` is used)

Comment: @Martin: I disagree. Choosing the wrong data structure on purpose is counter-productive. Why not start out with an existing one that maps well to your problem domain? The only reason to "optimize later" is to save developer time, since often the hot path is not quite where we expect. But it takes exactly the same amount of time to choose a `std::deque` over a `std::vector`.

Comment: Did you try declaring the move constructor as `noexcept`?

Comment: @imreal as I have mentioned in my question, I use `std::deque<std::function<void()>>` where `std::function<void()>` is move-only.

Comment: In what way is `std::function<void()>` move-only?

Comment: @Cameron: I don't much care about the difference between std::deque and std::vector.  I expect both to be acceptable;unless this is the hot path, I don't expect there to be a measurable difference.  If the number of elements is usually small, I would expect vector to be faster (better cache locality).  My major quibble is with "often the hot path is not quite where we expect"; I would phrase that as "almost always the hot path is nowhere near where we expect".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic example of why a [MCVE] is so useful.

```
std::function<void()> fun = std::move(queue.front());
```

The above won't compile with a non-copyable content in the `queue`.  But the `queue` works fine.  `std::deque` solves your problem.

`std::function` requires its contents to be copyable.  Even if you never move it, it requires it be copyable.  `std::function` uses type erasure, so "how to copy" the contents is stored when you store something in it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25408989/1774667) is a move-only `std::function` that does not do the small buffer optimization I wrote on SO two years ago.

Today I would write it differently.  I would split the type erasure from the storage, and write a separate SBO storage type, then join them together to write `task<Sig>`.

Amusingly, `packaged_task<void(Args...)>` is a type erased SBO move-only wrapper for `packaged_task<R(Args...)>`.  But it does much more, so I would avoid using it.

Now, the rules for std containers with regards to the requirements for their content have varied, with the standard regularly getting more liberal.  At one point a bunch of requirements where placed on types even if it wasn't used; the current standard states that these requirements are on a per-method basis.  Many compilers enforced those more liberal requirements before the standard moved (because there was little need to be strict, the standard did not demand it), so even in compilers prior to the liberalization it wasn't a problem.  I am uncertain if this liberalization occurred in `std::deque` by C++11 or not; this is, however, an example of "if it works in your compiler, use it, because future compilers are going to support it".