# Why local variables in the lambda object are const?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

Following code doesn't compile. Because `pt` has type of `const std::packaged_task<void()>>` and `operator()` is not `const`.

```
auto packagedTask = std::packaged_task<void()>>([]{});
auto future = packagedTask.get_future();
auto function = [pt = std::move(packagedTask)]{ (*pt)(); });
```

Here is workaround:

```
auto packagedTask = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<void()>>([]{});
auto future = packagedTask->get_future();
auto function = [pt = std::move(packagedTask)]{ (*pt)(); });
```

Why local variables in the lambda object are `const`?
I want to make first code work without overheads to workarounds. What is best practice to solve the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless the lambda is marked as `mutable`, the generated `lambda::operator()` will be qualified as `const`. Marking your lambda as `mutable` will prevent this behavior:

```
auto function = [pt = std::move(packagedTask)]() mutable { (*pt)(); });
```

---

> Why local variables in the lambda object are `const`?

Local variables in *closures* generated by *lambda expressions* are not `const`. It's the generated `lambda::operator()` that's qualified as `const`. A better question might be *"Why is a lambda's `operator()` implicitly `const`?*

It's because `const` is a better default than `mutable`. Mutability introduces complexity. Immutability makes code easier to reason about.

`const` should be the language-wide default, but that's impossible to change due to retrocompatibility. Since lambdas were a brand new feature, the committee decided to go with `const` by-default and opt-in mutability.

Comment: Thanks! I need to store lambda objects in `std::function` but lambda with `std::package_task` cannot be assigned: `std::function<void()> f = [pt = std::move(packagedTask)]() mutable { pt(); };`

Comment: `std::function` does not support move-only callables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330716/move-only-version-of-stdfunction