# Can I get return type auto to work with lambdas of the same signature but different captures?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, auto

I'm trying to use auto as the return type for a returned lambda function. Here's a minimal example that demonstrates a problem I'm having with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

auto
get_func()
{
    auto i = std::make_unique<int>(2);
    if (*i == 1) {
        return [i=std::move(i)]() {
            return *i;
        };
    }
    return [](){ return 2; };
}

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto func = get_func();
    std::cout << "val: " << func() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

On my mac, I get the following compile error:

```
$ g++ -g -Wall -Werror -std=c++17 test.cc -o test
test.cc:13:5: error: 'auto' in return type deduced as '(lambda at test.cc:13:12)' here but deduced as '(lambda at test.cc:9:16)' in earlier return statement
    return [](){ return 2; };
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Right, they're both deduced as `lambda`. And they both have the same `void(void)` signature. Am I seeing problems because they specify different captures? If so, what are my options for getting the same function call for the caller to work (as seen in the `cout` call in `main`).

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330716/move-only-version-of-stdfunction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I seeing problems because they specify different captures?

You would have seen a problem even if they were exactly the same, token for token.

Each lambda expression creates a **unique** closure type, which is different from  any closure type created by any other lambda. There is no reconciling this difference, so `auto` deduction cannot succeed.

You'll need to type erase the actual functor if you intend to return two different lambdas (either with `std::function`, or a custom type that supports move only semantics). That, or perhaps roll the entire logic into a single lambda:

```
auto
get_func()
{
    auto i = std::make_unique<int>(2);
    return [i=std::move(i)]() {
        if (*i == 1) {
            return *i;
        }
        return 2;
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you post a code example of this working? As I mentioned to @NathanOliver, the captured unique_ptr seems to preclude std::function.

Comment: @firebush - That always gets me. I'm afraid `std::function` won't do indeed. This is an impasse with the standard library, and will require a custom type erasing functor.

Comment: Thanks @storyteller. This confirms this limitation.

Answer (score 2):

> And they both have the same `void(void)` signature.

While the lambda's have the same `operator()` signature, they are not the same class type. They are distinct objects with distinct types.  Auto return type deduction requires that all return statements have the same type, which you don't have here.

In this case where you have different types you need a common return type.  You can get that with `std::function` as it lets you return by the `operator()` type instead of the lambda type.  That gives you

```
std::function<void(void)> get_func()
{
    auto i = std::make_unique<int>(2);
    if (*i == 1) {
        return [i=std::move(i)]() {
            return *i;
        };
    }
    return [](){ return 2; };
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm in a catch 22 then. Your example doesn't compile: I cannot use std::function because I require the use of std::make_unique captured by move. Since std::function requires the ability to Copy (which is not supported by std::unique_ptr) this doesn't compile.

Comment: @firebush D'oh.  Missed it was move only.  Yeah, this won't work.  You'd need a version that supports move only functors like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330716/move-only-version-of-stdfunction

Comment: OK, this is helpful as it informs me of the parameters I have to work with. I'll use shared_ptr instead because it is copyable and move that into the lambda via capture. Then I'll use the std::function as you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @firebush No problem.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best variant *(foreshadowing pun intended)* is StoryTeller's solution to put the logic inside a single lambda.

For fun, as an alternative, you can use a variant to hold your lambda. And you can create a simple wrapper around it:

```
template <class... Fs>
struct Lambda_fixed_variant
{
    std::variant<Fs...> f_;

    template <class L>
        // requires std::is_constructible_v<decltype(f_), std::in_place_type_t<L>, L&&>
    Lambda_fixed_variant(L l)
        : f_{std::in_place_type_t<L>{}, std::move(l)}
    {}

    template <class... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) const
    {
        return std::visit([&] (const auto& l) {
                return l(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            },
            f_
            );
    }
};

auto get_func()
{
    auto i = std::make_unique<int>(2);

    auto l1 = [i=std::move(i)]() { return *i; };
    auto l2 = [](){ return 2; };

    using L1 = decltype(l1);
    using L2 = decltype(l2);

    if (true)
    {
        return Lambda_fixed_variant<L1, L2>{std::move(l1)};
    }
    return Lambda_fixed_variant<L1, L2>{l2};
}
```