# Capture arguments are copied from rvalue lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function

Are captured arguments copied during the conversion of lambdas to `std::function`?
I need to convert a lambda that captures a non-copyable type to `std::function`.
So I passed a lambda to `std::function` as an rvalue, but an error occurred.

```
// Foo is non-copyable.
auto a = [f = Foo()]{ };
std::function<void()> b = std::move(a) // error, calls deleted Foo::Foo(const Foo&);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to create an std::function from a move-capturing lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421346/how-to-create-an-stdfunction-from-a-move-capturing-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) requires the function object to be [CopyConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible) and can't be used with move-only function objects.

> Type requirements
>
> - `F` must meet the requirements of [*Callable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) and [*CopyConstructible*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible).

You can wrap the lambda into [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) like `std::function<void()> b = std::ref(a);`, but then you have to be careful of the lifetime of the lambda object. Or you may try to stop using `std::function` and use lambda directly; especially in template context.

Comment: First of all thank you for the answers. But I could not find one of your answers that could solve my problem. Because what I want to make is to bind an argument to a function and store that function in a queue. Is there any other way to solve my problem?

Comment: @blAs1N: You would have to write something like `std::function`, but which only requires moveability. That's too big of a task for a Stack Overflow Q&A.

Comment: Another solution is to write a callable wrapper for `shared_ptr<Foo>`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Maybe it's not _that_ big a task? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330716/move-only-version-of-stdfunction .