# C++ `std::move` custom type into a lambda capture

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a class in which I deleted the copy assignment operator and copy constructor, leaving only a move assignment operator and move constructor. For example:

```
struct Number {
  public:
  int *pNum;

  Number &operator=(const Number &rhs) = delete;
  Number(const Number &rhs) = delete;

  Number &operator=(Number &&rhs) {
    if (&rhs == this) {
      return *this;
    }

    pNum = rhs.pNum;
    rhs.pNum = nullptr;
    return *this;
  }

  Number() = default;

  Number(Number &&rhs) {
    *this = std::move(rhs);
  }

  ~Number() {
    delete pNum;
  }
};
```

Now, I want to use `std::move` to capture this class into a lambda. For example:

```
int main() {
  std::function<int(int)> add;


  int a = 3;

  {

    Number n{};
    n.pNum = new int;
    *n.pNum = 5;

    add = [&, capA{std::move(n)}](int) mutable -> int {
      int b = *capA.pNum; // 5
      return a + b; // 8
    };
  }

  std::cout << add(3);
}
```

However, it seems that `n` would be `const` so that c++ would try to use the deleted copy constructor. How would I fix this? (REPL: https://repl.it/@25GrantY/WeirdLambda)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem isn't with the lambda. E.g. this works:

```
auto l = [&, capA{std::move(n)}](int) mutable -> int {
      int b = *capA.pNum; // 5
      return a + b; // 8
    };
```

The problem is with `std::function` and this lambda. Because you capture a non-copyable object then the lambda is non-copyable. `std::function` requires its stored object to be copyable so that's why it doesn't work.

You can read more here: [Move-only version of std::function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330716/move-only-version-of-stdfunction)

Answer (score 5):

the problem here is coming from std::function.
This class must satisfy CopyConstructible and CopyAssignable requirements, according to documentation.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

> std::function satisfies the requirements of CopyConstructible and
>   CopyAssignable.

When you attempt to initialize std::function with a lambda that captured move-only type by value, such assignment (if successful) would violate the both of the requirements above.

This is why compilation fails with an error.

How to fix this?

Either do not use std::function, or make your lambda copyable.

You can use std::shared_ptr as a copyable wrapper for move-only type.

```
auto shared_number = std::make_shared<Number>{};
```

Now, you can pass shared_number to lambda, and assign to std::function.