# Why this code snippet works? The parameter of the lambda should be a lvalue-reference, whereas `std::bind` pass a rvalue(i.e. `std::move(ptr)`) to it

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does [this code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/x8h98oeh3) work?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int(666));

    std::bind([](std::unique_ptr<int> &ptr){std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;}, std::move(ptr))();
}
```

You see the parameter of the lambda should be a lvalue-reference, whereas `std::bind` pass a rvalue(i.e. `std::move(ptr)`) to it.

Also, why does [this code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/vjb156P1r) not compile?

```
std::function<void()> = std::bind([](std::unique_ptr<int> &ptr){std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;}, std::move(ptr));
```

Just because `std::function` need copy all the objects, whereas `std::move(ptr)` is not copyable?

UPDATED:

The aforementioned code which could not compile is seen at https://localcoder.org/how-to-capture-a-unique-ptr-into-a-lambda-expression (i.e. see the 'solution 3' in the post). So the said solution is totally wrong. Am I right?

Comment: “*Just because std::function need copy all the objects, whereas std::move(ptr) is not copyable?*” Yep, in such case you might want to use the C++23 [`std::move_only_function`](https://godbolt.org/z/rcT5d5ae7).

Comment: `C++23` is impossible for me. What I can use is `C++17`.

Comment: @John related: [Move-only version of std::function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330716/), [How to create an std::function from a move-capturing lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421346/)

Comment: @John it's not a lot of code to make a move-only function. I'd suggest putting it in a header and leaving a `// C++23: std::move_only_function` comment.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The code about the move-only version of `std::function` is too hard for me to understand. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::bind()` does not call the lambda, it returns a proxy that will call the lambda when the proxy is invoked later. So, just because *you* pass in an rvalue reference into `std::bind()` does not mean the *proxy* will pass an rvalue reference into the lambda.

And in fact, if you think about it, the proxy can't do so anyway.  It has to move your rvalue-referenced `unique_ptr` object into something in the proxy to save it for later use after `std::bind()` has exited.  And that something is itself not an rvalue, and so that something can then be passed into the lambda by lvalue reference.

Comment: Thank you, sincerely. I have a related question, please see the updated question.

Comment: @John I can't answer your other question. It ha something to do with stateless (non-capturing) lambdas not being copy-constructible until recently. Your version of gcc likely hasn't implemented support for that.

Answer (score 1):

> std::bind pass a rvalue ... to it

Yes, an rvalue was passed to `std::bind`. It was duly stashed away for safe-keeping, until such time that the bound callable object gets called.

At that time the saved object gets passed to the lambda by referenced.

In other words, the following is a gross simplification, this is what this particular `std::bind` roughly ends up making something like this:

```
struct bound_function {

   template<typename Arg> bound_function(Arg &&arg)
      : saved_parameter{std::forward<Arg>(arg)}
   {
   }

   void operator()()
   {
       invoke_bound_function(saved_parameter);
   }

private:

   std::unique_ptr<int> saved_parameter;

   void invoke_bound_function(std::unique_ptr<int> &ptr){std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;}
};
```

The act of binding a parameter to a callable object, and then invoking a callable object with a bound parameter, are two discrete, independent events. In the first one, the parameter is moved into the bound object, as an rvalue reference.

Invoking the bound function is a separate step, and the bound parameter gets passed to the bound function, by reference.

Comment: How to understand " It was duly stashed away for safe-keeping, until such time that the bound callable object gets called" in the right way?

Comment: At first glance, there is a member function whose name is the same with the class, which makes me confused. :(

Comment: It can be understood literally. The parameter that was passed in by rvalue doesn't just get suspended, like a zombie, in the ether, until it's passed along to the callable object. It has to be saved somewhere. Then, when it's time to call the lambda it gets passed. And a "function whose name is the same with the class" is called a "constructor". One of the first points of discussion in every C++ textbook's first chapter on classes is an explanation of what a constructor a destructor is, how they work, how to declare them, and how they're used.