# Why can't I move a mutable function that contains a moved future?

Tags: c++, lambda, mutable, move-constructor

I'm basically trying do do this:

```
using Type = SomeTypeThatIWantToMove;

std::promise<Type> promised_result;
std::future<Type> promised_future = promised_result.get_future();

using Callback = std::function<void()>;

Callback function_which_should_be_movable =
            [this, future_result(std::move(promised_future))]() mutable
{
    this->some_function(future_result.get());   // signature: void some_function(const Type&)
};

using ResultBuilder = std::function<Type(Callback&&)>;

// result_builder is of type ResultBuilder  
Type thingy = result_builder(std::move(function_which_should_be_movable));
```

MinGW tell me, that the Move-Constructor of function_which_should_be_movable is deleted, because the Copy-constructor of std::future is deleted. However, I don't see why the compiler would attempt to copy the future instead of moving it.

Comment: The unfortunate reality is that `std::function` is pretty badly broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`function_which_should_be_movable` is of type `std::function`. According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function):

> `template< class F > function( F f );` `F` must meet the requirements
>   of `Callable` and `CopyConstructible`.

The lambda expression you try to use to construct an `std::function` object is not copyable, and hence the problem.

As to why `std::function` has this requirement, please see this question: [Why the initializer of std::function has to be CopyConstructible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658546/why-the-initializer-of-stdfunction-has-to-be-copyconstructible) (which is asked exactly by myself). Simply put, the type erasure technique used by `std::function` will instantiate the copy-constructor of `F`. This happens regardless of whether you, the user of the `std::function` object, actually used this copy-constructor or not.

Comment: In this case, what is the point of C++14's Lambda capture expressions? The idea is to allow something like this: std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int(10)); auto lambda = [value = std::move(ptr)] {return *value;}; So why would I move something into a function object, if the function object itself gets stuck at its place forever, because the moved object disables copying or moving.

Comment: Then you need something else than `std::function`. Something like it, but without type erasure. So you could avoid instantiating the copy-constructor by not using it.

Comment: Constructing the function object is not the problem, even if function_which_should_be_movable would not be copyable. I can construct it and call it in place. The error only occurs when I try to move the object. But again: I don't see why a deleted copy-constructor prevents me from moving the function. Where is the copy-constructor called in the move process?

Comment: Constructing the function object is a problem. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a20c84f4237fbeb. Constructing such a function object instantiates all its virtual member functions, and the copy-constructor of the supplied type is called in one of them. Virtual member functions will by no means be optimized out.