# Overhead with std::function

Tags: c++, function, c++11, c++14

I have seen many instances where people have advised against using `std::function<>` because it is a heavyweight mechanism. Could someone please explain why that is so?

Comment: What's the alternative? I'm asking because in certain context there's no other alternative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the performance overhead of std::function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057382/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-stdfunction)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::function` is a type erasure class.

It takes whatever it is constructed from, and erases everything except:

- Invoke with the signature in question (with possible implicit casting)
- Destroy
- Copy
- Cast back to exact original type

and possibly

- Move

This involves some overhead.  A typical decent-quality `std::function` will have small object optimization (like small string optimization), avoiding a heap allocation when the amount of memory used is small.

A function pointer will fit in there.

However, there is still overhead.  If you initialize a `std::function` with a compatible function pointer, instead of directly calling the function pointer in question, you do a virtual function table lookup, or invoke some other function, which then invokes the function pointer.

With a vtable implementation, that is a possible cache miss, an instruction cache miss, then another instruction cache miss.  With a function pointer, the pointer is probably stored locally, and it is called directly, resulting on one possible instruction cache miss.

On top of this, in practice compilers understand function pointers better than `std::function`s: a number of compilers can figure out that the pointer is constant value during inlining or whole program optimization.  I have never seen one that pulls that off with `std::function`.

For larger objects (say larger than `sizeof(std::string)` in one implementation), a heap allocation is also done by the `std::function`.  This is another cost.  For function pointers and reference wrappers, SOO is guaranteed by the standard.

---

Directly storing the lambda without storing it in a `std::function` is even better than a function pointer: in that case, the code being run is implicit in the type of the lambda.  This makes it trivial for code to work out what is going to happen when it is called, and inlining easy for the compiler.

Only do type erasure when you need to.

Comment: The small-object optimization is guaranteed for function pointers and `reference_wrapper`s.

Comment: @T.C. Does `std::function` make any mention of references-to-functions? I couldn't see any on _cppreference_ (not that that is conclusive, obviously). A quick test indicates that it can be constructed from one and works OK, but I don't know if that proves much. Is the reference simply converted to a pointer? Either way, I would expect the case of references to be mentioned somewhere.

Comment: @underscore_d The constructor takes by value, so it's always decayed.

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood, `std::function` typically uses type erasure (one simplified explanation for how it may be implemented is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658546/why-the-initializer-of-stdfunction-has-to-be-copyconstructible/24659209#24659209)).  The cost of storing your function object inside the `std::function` object may involve a heap allocation.  The cost of invoking your function object is typically an indirection through a pointer plus a virtual function call.  Also, while compilers are getting better at this, the virtual function call usually inhibits inlining of your function.

That being said, I recommend using `std::function` unless you know via measurements that the cost is too high (typically when you cannot afford heap allocations, your function will be called many times in a place that requires very low latency, etc.), as it is better to write straightforward code than to prematurely optimize.

Answer (score 1):

Depending of the implementation, `std::function` will add some overhead due to the use of type easure. They have been some other implementation such as Don Clugston's fast delegate, with a C++11 implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/SuperV1234/6462221). Please note that it uses UB to make the fastest possible delegate, but is still extremely portable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want type erasure it's the right tool for the job and almost certainly not your bottleneck and not something you could write faster anyway.

However sometimes it can be all to tempting to use type erasure when it really isn't required. That's where to draw the line. For example if all you want to do is keep hold of a lambda locally then it's probably not the right tool and you should just use:

```
auto l = [](){};
```

Likewise for function pointers you don't plan to type erase - just use a function pointer type.

You also don't need type erasure for templates from `<algorithm>` or your own equivalents because there's simply no need for heterogenous functor types to coexist.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so.

To put it simply, it's not too heavyweight unless you profiled your program and showed that it is too heavyweight. Since evidently you did not (otherwise you would know the answer to this question), we can safely conclude that it is in fact not too heavyweight at all.

You should always profile, before concluding that it's too slow.

Comment: This isn't a useful answer. The OP is asking about _why_ it might be the case, and no amount of profiling is going to answer such a _why_ question. It's also silly for you to claim that because OP hasn't profiled, it's not too heavyweight; that's a non-sequitur. It was a tall horse you climbed on just to hit someone over the head with Hoare's dictum.