# Why require copy constructor for packaged_task in VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, packaged-task

```
class MoveOnlyOperation
{
public:
    MoveOnlyOperation()                         = default;
    MoveOnlyOperation(const MoveOnlyOperation&) = delete;
    MoveOnlyOperation(MoveOnlyOperation&&)      = default;

    int operator()()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

I want to wrap an object instance inside a packaged_task like this:

```
std::packaged_task<void()> task(MoveOnlyOperation{});
```

I get "*error C2280: 'MoveOnlyOperation::MoveOnlyOperation(const MoveOnlyOperation &)': attempting to reference a deleted function*"

The documentation for C++ 11 says one can perfect forward the instance inside the packaged_task though. I also don't have issues with clang.

It there something implementation defined about how packaged_task should be implemented or a bug in VS 2015 (and possibly later because I get same issue with http://rextester.com/WBEH22233)

Comment: Not all versions of VS support all the C++11 features. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx.

Comment: Yes, but this seems to be a library bug

Comment: I hope somebody with more knowledgeable than me will be able to help you out.

Comment: This looks like a library bug to me. MSVC is storing the callable in `std::function`, which imposes the copyable requirement. I don't see anything in the standard that says the callable needs to be copy constructible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/108672/unable-to-move-stdpackaged-task-into-any-stl-conta.html) in MSVC's `packaged_task` implementation. They're storing the callable within `std::function`, which [requires](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25330716/241631) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24658546/241631) the argument be copy-constructible.

Answer (score 0):

As @Praetorian said, it's MSVC's known bug.

It caused trouble to me, to put lambda function with moving captured `std::unique_ptr`, into `std::packaged_func`.
And I'm doing Linux / Windows cross platform, note it works perfectly well in Linux system.

Use its original source: [boost::fibers::packaged_task](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/fiber/doc/html/fiber/synchronization/futures/packaged_task.html) fixed the problem for me.